# want to create sql Pivot on user entered date range, @Cols. How do I declare @fromDate, @toDate in the procedure? Date is a field on Item table

Tags: sql, dynamic, parameters, pivot

```
select *
From
(
Select 
st.site_code
si.item_code
from c_item i
inner join c.item_code ic on i.item_key=ic.item_key

)PVT
Pivot
(Count(si.item_code)for [DATE] in [' + @Cols + ']P
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the date table to get the all dates b/w `@fromDate` and `@toDate` from the user input. You can use the existing time table or make one and use the date value from the table to create the desired columns b/w from date and to date.

A sample code is attached below.

```
create or alter procedure pivot_table_with_user_input
(
@from_Date varchar(10),
@to_Date varchar(10)
)
as
begin

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [CalendarTable]
CREATE TABLE [CalendarTable]
(
    [CalendarDate] varchar(10)
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = (select dateadd(yy, -10, convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 121)))    --10 years back from the current date
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(yy, 10, @StartDate)                                          --10 years in the future from the current date

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [CalendarTable]
    SELECT convert(varchar(10), convert(date, @StartDate), 121)
               
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
END

declare @cols nvarchar(max) = ''
set @cols = STUFF(
                     (  select ',' + quotename(convert(varchar(10), t.CalendarDate))
                        from CalendarTable t
                        where t.CalendarDate between convert(date, @from_Date) and convert(date, @to_Date)
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
                );

select @cols column_value   --check the dynamic columns


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
select site_code, '+@cols+'
From
(
    Select site_code,item_code, date_field
    from c_item
)PVT
Pivot
(
    Count(item_code)for date_field in ('+@cols+')
)P
'
print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql

end
```

db<>fiddle [**link**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1348b245cc3e33606a40316496f9675c).